# post an array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

This one is long to explain but basically my controller is built and expects an array in 
`params[:order_items]`, so I've tried it like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "order_items", @order[:order_items_ids] %>
```

but I get the ids concatenated

```
<input id="gig_items" name="gig_items" type="hidden" value="2300124946">
```

So, How do I send and array in one of the `params` keys using just html (without js)?

Comment: sorry, I'm afraid of monsters...

Comment: ...but try: `<%= hidden_field_tag "order_items", @order[:order_items_ids].to_json %>
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can post it in a string joined by ',' like:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "order_items", @order[:order_items_ids].join(",") %>
```

then split it in your controller.
But if you really want it in an array. You can also do it like this:

```
<%@order[:order_items_ids].each do |oid|%>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "order_items[]", oid %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: nice and simple! completly saved my a@@! 10x!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it but there's maybe a better solution with html:

```
<% @order.order_items_ids.each do |o| %>
     <input id="order_items" name="order_items[]" type="hidden" value="<%= o %>" />
<% end %>
```

EDIT: Just to say, for order items, I would put it in session if I were you.